# how to install unsigned android application on the device?

Tags: android, testing, installation

Currently a team of developers is working on Android application and during the development process testers already have to test the current state and report issues.

So far I have simply installed the application by connecting the tester's device on my pc and hit run in the IDE. This way we waste a lot of time if an application has to be installed on multiple devices multiple times daily.

What I would like is to send the testing team the .apk file and let them install and run the application by themselves.

Does anyone know what's the best way to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: Note that "unsigned" is probably not what you are referring to here. When you create an APK during the normal development process, it is signed by a debug key. Such APKs can be distributed but will not work, for example, on the Android Market. A truly "unsigned" APK can be created, but it cannot be installed unless you manually sign it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can allow untrusted applications in the settings.

Settings / Applications / Unknown sources

with that setting on, you can just point your phone to the url of an .apk and install it IIRC.

It is also possible to install apks using debug mode and adb-commands over USB-cable.

Comment: Sometimes it's in Security instead of Applications

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I do for that, simple:
Build in debug mode, no need to sign with a special key.
Mail them the application by regular email to their computers. Then have them connect their USB cables (comes with the phone) and copy to sd card. Access the sd card from the within the phone using any  available file browser, and they can install it from the SD card.
Regards

Comment: On tablet, you can send .apk to some gmail and in tablet browser go on that email acount and download apk and run :)

Answer (score 1):

There is also software called Installapk that allows you to install APKs on your device very easily, though it is only available for Microsoft Windows, and is currently in beta.

[Installapk](http://android.modaco.com/content/software/288682/install-apks-on-your-device-by-double-clicking-on-your-pc-with-installapk-beta-1/)