# Android Application Signing

Tags: android, signing

It is written in [App-Signing](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html) that

> The Android system will not install or run an application that is not signed appropriately.

But, I am wondering why I can still run an unsigned application in the emulator. I am thinking that signing of an application is only needed when publishing the application. Is my understanding correct?

Thanks,
artsylar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The android system checks your application certificate every time you install it. When you run an application on emulator, IDE signs it for you with generated debug certificate.
You can see that it is true by performing an experiment:

From one computer install an application using IDE on your device.
Then try to install the same application from another computer. You will get an error while installing : wrong certificate.

Remember, that this debug certificate is valid until you want publish the application. Then you will need to create a keystore and properly sign the application. Don not forget to backup the keystore!

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I have tried installing a signed application compiled using eclipse from another computer via adb install command and I am still not getting any error with regards to the certificate.

Comment: Hehey, no. You should rebuild your application on another computer :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes...
If you are running over the emulator no need to sign the app because android build tool will do that automatically.

If you want to make it available to end users you must sign it with your private key to avoid tampering of an application.

Answer (score 0):

The application you are using in the emulator is signed at compile time with a debug certificate. So the app is signed but out of simplicity this is done automatically for you.

Answer (score 0):

check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763249/how-to-install-unsigned-android-application-on-the-device)

> Note that "unsigned" is probably not what you are referring to here. When you create an APK during the normal development process, it is signed by a debug key. Such APKs can be distributed but will not work, for example, on the Android Market. A truly "unsigned" APK can be created, but it cannot be installed unless you manually sign it